# apt-get fails within container without sudo

Tags: docker, containers, sudo

I have observed a problem where apt-get install  will fail within a container where:

1. the package is already installed and,
2. sudo is not used.

This can be recreated by creating a simple container, e.g.

```
docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Within the container, run the following:

```
apt-get install software-properties-common
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

The second time, this will fail with a "Killed" message. If you then prepend the statement with sudo it will complete successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

If the user within the container is root, why is sudo required to reinstall an existing package? I do not believe this is related to the AUFS file system as prepending with sudo will complete.

This is using docker 1.10 and an Ubuntu image.

Comment: You should do `apt-get update` first

Comment: If I do like you, the first apt-get installs, the second gives `software-properties-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.` so there is something wrong. Ubuntu 14.04, docker 1.10.2-rc1 for me

Comment: This makes no difference. The main point is the use of sudo. using apt-get install software-properties-common && apt-get update then apt-get install software-properties-common will fail.

If you then use sudo apt-get install software-properties-common, it will work. The heart of this problem is the requirement to use sudo, despite being root.

Comment: @user2915097 didn't work. ` apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Comment: actually I get this issue too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354928/bash-sudo-command-not-found

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72058458/run-ubuntu-docker-container-as-user-with-sudo-access creating a user in docker with sudo access

Comment: When neither sudo nor apt-get is available in container, you can also jump into running container as root user using command `docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/bash`. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

> The main point is the use of sudo

It doesn't fail on Debian 11:

```
# docker run -it ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
00f50047d606: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:20fa2d7bb4de7723f542be5923b06c4d704370f0390e4ae9e1c833c8785644c1
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
#  apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
# apt-get install software-properties-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.99.22.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

There may be something corrupt on your system. If running these don't help, you may need to reinstall:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to install sudo package by following commands.

apt update && apt upgrade
apt install sudo

Comment: The question is not how to install sudo. The question is why apt fails for the OP when running as root without sudo.